# Hyperledger Composer Query Language: How do you get an asset back from a relationship using the asset ID?

Tags: hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I have a "production record" asset on my blockchain which has a relationship to an "order" asset. Within the query language I cannot find a way to return the order/s using the orderId. The basic idea is I want an API endpoint that returns the production record for a certain order.

I have tried using "order.orderId = _$orderId" but this does not seem to work and I currently have

```
WHERE (order == (SELECT org.garment.supplychain.Order 
       WHERE (_$orderId = org.garment.supplychain.Order.orderId)))
```

but this gives me a syntax error.

Please see the code examples for my models.

```
asset ProductionRecord identified by productionId{
    o String productionId
    o ProductionDetails productionDetails
    --> Order order 
    --> Manufacturer factory
}

asset Order identified by orderId {
  o String orderId
  o GarmentDetails garmentDetails
  o OrderStatus orderStatus
  --> Customer orderer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
query ProductionRecordByOrder {
  description: "Get all the production records referring to the same order"
  statement:
    SELECT your.namespace.ProductionRecord 
    WHERE ( order == _$inputOrder )
}
```

and when you invoke this query, you will need to pass a *fully qualified identifier* like this

```
// you need to get the order object here before the query
// for example, the order might be a property in the transaction
var order = tx.order;

var ProductionRecord = await query( "ProductionRecordByOrder", {inputOrder: `resource:${order.getFullyQualifiedIdentifier()}`} );
```

Essentially and most importantly, the input will need to look something like this

```
resource:your.namespace.Order#some_order_id
```

I am assuming that you are using namespace but if not, just remove the namespaces (ie the part `your.namespace.`)